# How can the JVM return an exception object at run time for a checked exception, if checked exceptions occur at compile time?

Tags: java, exception

I understand that checked exceptions in Java are handled at compile time. If this is the case, how can the JVM return a checked exception object at run-time if we are still compiling the source code?

Comment: An exception thrown for example NumberFormatException , because you have entered a string in place of decimal value.
It's impossible for  jvm to detect this error at compile time.
Java isn't really compiled language like C or C++, it's jvm who interpret a intermediate language called byte code

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions (checked or unchecked) occur at runtime. The only difference is that checked exceptions must be handled (by either adding them to the throws clause of the method or a `try-catch` block); the handled part there is static code analysis - which determines one (or both) of those two conditions is met at compile time.

Comment: If exceptions are thrown at run-time, what is the role of the compiler in dealing with "checked exceptions" ?

Comment: Static code analysis to ensure the exception is handled. As I said.

Comment: So while compiling, the compiler will check to see if the "checked exception" is dealt with by the programmer. If not it tells the jvm to deal with it by returning an exception object(checked or unchecked) then the jvm searches for an exception handler, if it is not found it calls a default handler . Is this correct?

Comment: The "default handler" is usually to exit and display a stack trace. The analysis occurs at the level of the method. `public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {}` for example, is explicitly marking that a checked exception may "escape" `main` (exactly like an unchecked exception might). In the case of other methods, then the compiler will require that callers **check** for the marked exception (hence the name).

Comment: Would you say the most recent comment I gave is an accurate description of how exceptions are dealt with?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your recent comment. I suggest you examine the byte code with `javap` if you're still confused.